# How to build a specific branch of SVN in Jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins, svn, hook

I need build specific branch after each commit in jenkins with hooks.

I found hook like this

```
> # curl -X POST  https://myusername:551e08fbe02f9f455dd914c84fc525b7@jenkins.mydomain.com/job/myjobname/buildWithParameters?token=Eip3eeruaceecham9bauh7nei5veoyieleemielazai6ye8eeg
```

And it works.

But how can I know which branch should I build with jenkins? How can I build project for current commited branch version with jenkins?

What should I do in jenkins?